# String to Image java

Tags: java

I have to convert a string to an image, the string looks like this:

> ``` !?ò„ÁÁø?mDé¯ïÌA¤>Vbïììî­Ï½^/èõz²+öó¢ílãÊ… '­í¤ÛX¹-–Û?ÆêÕ ø×vý¹ÿàû•O_ž'ãàò?Euò6Î§?ç?¼ä”vE³•}Uœl#KWwöw'Ç²Ûˆ«­¸µ¶vUåŽeýGåšv€ºÇéð]Þžžg¹ÜŽ^s™æ÷òž?F“7ù1|ÌÇ³¡Ü½Çðåù˜®‘r-'w?•“ÚaJQc'‡ÖJÙaHƒaeË­éÿ<´``?_·¤‹Êäá!xÉgóáèçÓp~;¼ûþ8?¼Žïçw“Ñd:®17¨ÊÚ¶ÒØ}c[‹1K[U-’Ç?m,¦ËÊ®m?ÁË¢–…•Å¡¬ºk¾qjUn­²qÕIª¢^!?Ôo9a×¬ÊºèÐ½@§Öîmƒh%‹“¿?]ÉWTý›> €ˆ ```

... and so on.

I converted it to a byte array and then tried to convert it to an BufferedImage but I always get a null pointer exception. I did some research and found out that the reason is, that I have no inputstreamreader registered but I have no solution. my code looks like this so far:

```
public static BufferedImage decodeToImage(String imageString) {

    BufferedImage image = null;
    byte[] imageByte;
    try {
        BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
        imageByte = decoder.decodeBuffer(imageString);
        image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByte));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return image;
}
```

If somebody could help me, I would be really glad.

Edit:

The data comes from a server its for an university project is send a command to the server and thats the answer of the server when using readline on the inputstream.

Comment: What image type would you like to convert it to?

Comment: Where did that string come from to start with? Fundamentally, binary data is *not* text - and that's certainly not Base64. You should either *actually* base64-encode the original image, or avoid using strings at all. As for the NullPointerException - I suspect that's because you're effectively ignoring the *actual* exception you're doing. Stop doing that - if the decode fails, do you *really* want to just return null?

Comment: How about `imageByte = imageString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);`?

Comment: So, it appears your server is sending you the image itself, *not* a string, a byte stream. Do not read it using a `Reader`. Read it using the input stream directly into ImageIO.

Comment: when i use just `Image image = ImageIO.read(socket.getInputStream());`
image is always null